# Protractor proxy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, gulp, protractor, e2e-testing

I work on project using angularJS and rails. I try to create e2e tests. Before testing I open server on localhost:5000, then I start 'gulp' starts server with frontend on localhost:3000. During test protractor connects with rails server and I get

```
[HPM] Proxy error: ECONNRESET. localhost:3000 -> "localhost:5000/v1/locations/frontend_data"
```

How can I turn off this message?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you looked at this? Do you have proxy configuration like mentioned here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/124

Comment: When I set 'httpProxy': 'localhost.com:5000' then protractor can't find 'http://localhost:3000/account/board/test'